# Frozen Columns Vertical Scroll Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zjppcdq6/1/)

I have written code to keep fixed first 2 columns & other columns are `horizontally` `scrollable`.

My problem is, I want a `fixed height` set to the `table` so that it is `vertically` also `scrollable`.

```
<div class="table-responsive" style="width: 400px; overflow-x:scroll; margin-left:354px;">
<table class="table table-bordered" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr class="tblHeadings">
            <th class="fixCol1 headCol">
                <div style="height: 40px;padding-top: 19px;">Code</div>
            </th>
            <th class="fixCol2 headCol">
                <div style="height: 40px;padding-top: 19px;">Name</div>
            </th>
            <th style="width:120px;height: 54px;">Days
                <input type="hidden" name="monthlyField" value="LD">
            </th>                
            <th style="width:120px;height: 54px;">EARNG1
                <input type="hidden" name="monthlyField" value="EARNG1">
            </th>
            <th style="width:120px;height: 54px;">EARNG2
                <input type="hidden" name="monthlyField" value="EARNG2">
            </th>                
            <th style="width:100px">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="fixCol1">GT001
                <input type="hidden" name="empID" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="empCode" value="GT001">
            </td>
            <td class="fixCol2">Brock</td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" max="31" step="0.01" value="" name="1|LD" class="form-control tdTextboxes">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" step="0.01" value="" name="1|WEEKOFF_DAYS" class="form-control tdTextboxes">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" step="0.01" value="" name="1|EARNG1" class="form-control tdTextboxes">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" step="0.01" value="" name="1|EARNG2" class="form-control tdTextboxes">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" step="0.01" value="" name="1|EARNG3" class="form-control tdTextboxes">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" step="0.01" value="" name="1|EARNG4" class="form-control tdTextboxes">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" step="0.01" value="" name="1|EARNG5" class="form-control tdTextboxes">
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn pr-btn-black-sm" type="button" onclick="deleteRecord(this,'1')">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="fixCol1">GT002
                <input type="hidden" name="empID" value="2">
                <input type="hidden" name="empCode" value="GT002">
            </td>
            <td class="fixCol2">John</td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" max="31" step="0.01" value="" name="2|LD" class="form-control tdTextboxes">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" step="0.01" value="" name="2|WEEKOFF_DAYS" class="form-control tdTextboxes">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" step="0.01" value="" name="2|EARNG1" class="form-control tdTextboxes">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" step="0.01" value="" name="2|EARNG2" class="form-control tdTextboxes">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" step="0.01" value="" name="2|EARNG3" class="form-control tdTextboxes">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" step="0.01" value="" name="2|EARNG4" class="form-control tdTextboxes">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" step="0.01" value="" name="2|EARNG5" class="form-control tdTextboxes">
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn pr-btn-black-sm" type="button" onclick="deleteRecord(this,'2')">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="fixCol1">GT003
                <input type="hidden" name="empID" value="3">
                <input type="hidden" name="empCode" value="GT003">
            </td>
            <td class="fixCol2">Walker Ross</td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" max="31" step="0.01" value="" name="3|LD" class="form-control tdTextboxes">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" step="0.01" value="" name="3|WEEKOFF_DAYS" class="form-control tdTextboxes">
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn pr-btn-black-sm" type="button" onclick="deleteRecord(this,'3')">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since it looks like you're using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), I took the liberty to make [a Bootply demo](http://www.bootply.com/X69G0dPn0M) of what you're trying to achieve.

You already had the solution really, the only thing was to apply fixed height to the `table-responsive` class rather than to the `table` class.

So I simply added `height:200px;` to the right class (btw, in general try to avoid in-line styling).

Comment: As you can see the frozen columns should also come under vertical scroll.

Comment: @Anup I'm not sure you can achieve that with your current set-up. Your classes `fixCol1` and `fixCol2` are taking the two columns out of the flow of the table. Have see this already http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/FixedColumns/examples/bootstrap.html?